# My TDBgrid is showing 1899/12/30 in a Time Field

Tags: ms-access, delphi-2010

My TDbgrid is displaying "1899/12/30 23:00" in a time field. I have connected the database via a dynamic link , so i cannot change anything via design. I am aware that there  is solution to this on StackOverflow but i cannot use the solution because my database is connected dynamically. Is there a way to display the time only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, as the "zero date" value of DateTime is Access in 1899-12-30.

Thus, your time value of your sample is 23:00:00.

However, a DateTime value *carries no format*, so the solution is up to you - apply the format you wish to the value whenever you wish to display the time - in your case, the format will most likely be `hh:nn` (in VBA, don't know about Delphi).